# Installing Android Studio in several Windows computers

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Java developer who is learning Android. I installed Android Studio in my machine, but it takes half an hour to download and install the packages I need.

Since I am a teacher and I eventually want to install Android Studio for my students, I wonder if there is a way to install Android Studio (with the packages and settings I have chosen) in several Windows computers (about 40), without having to wait for packages to download and install for each computer (which takes a lot of time). Thank you.

Comment: As it seams to install it one every pc via the installer would be the cleanest way to do this. I am not familiar with the windows installation but under Linux it should be possible to just copy the android studio folder and set the env. variables on every pc to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install ANdroid Studio in a network drive ?

A idea. Maybe if you want to monitor your students , you should syncronyze Android Studio projects across multiple workstations.